# Tab.Screen does not re-render

Tags: reactjs

`data` should update when useEffect runs, and it does. However, the change doesn't cause a rerender in the `Liked` page of the Tab Navigator, where it is passed as a route.params parameter.

Why doesn't the re-render happen?

Below is the parent component Home.js, that has a Tab.Navigator as a child. I pass in the data of note `data` into the `videoData` initial param of the tab navigator. However, when I update `data`, `videoData` never updates as well.

Home.js

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([{name: 'test'}]);
  console.log('DATA', data);
  // {lastVisible} for keep track of firebase paging
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
  const navigator = 
  <Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="posts" component={FeedList} initialParams={{videoData: route.params.videoData}} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Liked" component={FeedList} initialParams={{videoData: data, test: 'helloworld'}} />
</Tab.Navigator>;

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchChatGroups().then((ar) => {
      setData(ar);
    });
   },[]);

...
return <>{navigator}</>
```

Is initialParams not subject to re-renders of useState variables of parent components? When I print the value of `route.params.videoData` in FeedList, I get the following:

```
[Sat Jan 02 2021 19:54:41.145]  LOG      [{"name":"test"}]
```

which means the state stayed as default, even though I confirmed that the state does change with a console print with this line: `console.log('DATA', data);`

Comment: the re-render only happes when you mention the state in useEffect dependency array, `useEffect(()=>{ //you logic},[data])`

Comment: thanks for the comment. That wasn't it, though. Still doesn't update.

Comment: instead of using `const` can you use `var` and see if it work in `const navigator`

Comment: it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Were you able to finally work this out ?

Comment: Tab.Navigator renderes only ones if u want to change data in 2 or more pages use redux for storing the data it will update the screens whenever stored data changes

Answer (score 1):

Try to move this line of code `const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();` outside the component or wrap with `useMemo`.

Comment: didn't work. was a good idea though. didn't realize i was making a new tab navigator every render

Comment: Could you use `setParams` instead pass the props. I think `initialParams` skipped for rerender.

Comment: how do i use setParams here? I don't have access to the navigator yet. Could you maybe edit your answer with what you mean? thanks`

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for Tab.Screen re-render when the state value changes, I think this might help you.

Check this stack flow for more information:
[blog]: [React native: React navigation tab screen does not update if children is not an inline function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893239/react-native-react-navigation-tab-screen-does-not-update-if-children-is-not-an)

So, in order to re-render the component we need to pass props to component as children.
Example:

```
<Tab.Screen name="posts" component={FeedList} />
```

Here, instead of using `component={FeedList}`, you can use children =>

```
<Tab.Screen name="posts" children={()=>this.FeedList(Pass Props Here)} />
```

The above example is for class component.

Other examples:

```
 // Inside render()
 <Tab.Screen
    name="Account"
  //component={this.AccountScreen}
    children={() =>
      this.AccountScreen(this.props.schoolInformationPending)
    }
    options={{
     tabBarLabel: 'Account',
    }}
  />

// Inside Class Component
 AccountScreen = (props: any) => {
    return (<View><Text>{props.value}</Text></View>)
 }
```