# React native: React navigation tab screen does not update if children is not an inline function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I encounter a very weird behavior in my tab screen code. I was trying to pass an extra props into the screen component so I decided to create a arrow function that return the desire component (upcomingOrderView). When I try to call this function inside Tab screen component, it did work perfectly, but when this.state.bookingsBucket.upcoming got updated the screen did not re render. Here's the code:

```
class A extends React.Component {
    upcomingOrderView = (props) =>{
        return (
            <BookingsOrderView 
                {...props} 
                bookings={this.state.bookingsBucket.upcoming}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
       ...
       <Tab.Screen 
         name={"testRoute"} 
       >
         {this.upcomingOrderView}
       </Tab.Screen>
    }
}
```

I found a way to fix it, which is by creating an inline function that call upcomingOrderView but I don't understand why does this fix it. Anyone know what's the difference between the 2 code?

Fix code

```
render() {
    ...
    <Tab.Screen 
        name={"testRoute"} 
    >
        {(props) => this.upcomingOrderView(props)}
    </Tab.Screen>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, react navigation is rendering the `Screen` in a memoized component, which is the `StaticContainer` here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/SceneView.tsx#L115

In the case where `this.upcomingOrderView` is passed directly, the function reference never changes, so the memoized `StaticComponent` does not re-render even though the `state` that `this.upcomingOrderView` depends on has changed and the parent `A` component is re-rendering.

By using an inline function, the reference changes on every render of `A`, so `StaticComponent` re-renders every time `A` re-renders and the state change is picked up.